# for loop gives only last value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created variable outside to get values from inside but I only get last value in both variables.

```js
var categoryProductid;
var PPProducttitle;

for (var key in UpdatedCategory) {

  const actual = UpdatedCategory[key]
  var categoryProductid = actual.id;
  var PPProducttitle = actual.title;

  console.log(PPProducttitle)
  console.log(categoryProductid)
}

console.log(PPProducttitle)
console.log(categoryProductid)
```

when I do console.logs() from inside and outside of for loop I get two different values.

Any help will be appreciated thank you!!!!!

Comment: Why do you expect them to give the same values?

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: i don't expect them to give different values, i only want same values.

Comment: _"when I do console.logs() from inside and outside of for loop I get two different values"_? --- Ok, then why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: if i will use let how to access it from outside of for loop??

Comment: @swapnilagrawal - You're repeatedly assigning to the same variable, naturally the last assignment wins. If you want to retain multiple values, you have to use something that can hold multiple values (an array, an object, a Map, a Set, ...).

Comment: kinda odd using const as well?

Comment: @johnSmith - Heh, actually that's the one part that seems right to me. :-)

Comment: @T.J Crowder How Sir ? I am new to programming and trying to find out from last two days

Comment: @ceving - Yes, I know. I deleted the comment almost immediately. I'd just misread the code.

Comment: @swapnilagrawal - I suggest working through a good beginner's tutorial or book. Stack Overflow's Q&A format isn't designed for tutorials or individual tuition.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Sir, If you will tell, someone will also get to learn from this.

Comment: Search the internet for *javascript tutorial* or *javascript documentation*. Look at everything on the first page and find one that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `UpdatedCategory` is an object (if it's an array, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for what to use instead of `for-in` to loop through it).

The basic problem with that code is that you're assigning to the same variable over and over. The reason it's the same variable is that `var` doesn't have block scope, so the `var` part of `var categoryProductid = actual.id;` is completely ignored (and similar for `var PPProducttitle = actual.title;`). Instead, you're reusing the variables you declared prior to the `for` loop.

A variable can only hold one value, so when you assign a new value to it, it no longer holds the old value.

If you want to hold multiple values with a variable, you can assign a container to it that can hold multiple values, such as an array, an object, a `Map`, or a `Set`.

You haven't said what end result you want, but here's an example that creates two arrays and fills them with the `id` and `title` of the products from `UpdatedCategory`:

```js
// Again, I'm assuming `UpdatedCategory` is an object:
const UpdatedCategory = {
    a: {
        id: 1,
        title: "a",
    },
    b: {
        id: 2,
        title: "b",
    },
    c: {
        id: 3,
        title: "c",
    },
};

// `[]` creates a new empty array.
// We can use `const` to declare these because we never change their
// value (they only ever refer to a single array), but you could use
// `let` if you preferred. Don't use `var` in new code, it's deprecated.
// Note: I've renamed these slightly to:
// 1. Stick to standard naming conventions
//     * Initial capitals are used primarily for constructor functions
//     * Variables referring to arrays are generally plurals
// 2. Be consistent in capitalization
const categoryProductIds = [];
const ppProductTitles = [];

for (var key in UpdatedCategory) {
    // Get this property value
    const actual = UpdatedCategory[key];

    // Push the `id` and `title` into the relevant arrays
    categoryProductIds.push(actual.id);
    ppProductTitles.push(actual.title);
}

// Show the contents of the arrays
console.log(ppProductTitles);
console.log(categoryProductIds);
```